# Drupal account: score and badges not fit in the cell

Tags: bug, design

If you look at your account from [Drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) account, you can see the following:
[image]

Here is the class of hyperlink that can affect this:

```
.site-hyperlink {
    color: #0077C0 !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

If removed this line:

```
font-size: 16px !important;
```

Then the score and badges fits in the cell.

[image]

Comment: No repro here...what OS/browser are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I m using an operating system Windows 7. I m looked to the page in two browsers:
in `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0` and 
`Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Edition Yx) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.12`.In the Opera everything displayed fine in Firefox - no.

Comment: But still. Even in the Opera. If you inspect the element and add some numbers, they will not fit in the cell.

Comment: In `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko`  the same.

Comment: Thanks @Alexy, I'll check it out on Windows later on. I can't actually do anything about it, but hopefully this info will help the devs confirm

Comment: @Clive have you checked his meta profile http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12559/alexey repro in Updated FF - Windows 7. I think it is happening because of the long site name  **Programming Puzzles & Code Gol**

Comment: @Bala Haven't been on a Windows machine for a while now - I'll fire up a VM to have a look at some point, just finding time

Comment: Are you zoomed in at all? I can't reproduce this under normal circumstances, but zooming to 110-125% will do it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No, I changed zoom in `Firefox` from `30%` to `100%`, but it is not affected. Also does not fit.